# Oracle MAX gives different result than ORDER BY desc

Tags: oracle, query, order-by

When trying to sort some hexadecimal values I've got a different results for MAX() aggregation and ORDER BY desc sorting:

```
with some_data as
(
    select '123A55' as hex
    from dual
    union all
    select '123255' as hex
    from dual
)

select max(hex)
from some_data
;

Result: 123A55

with some_data as
(
    select '123A55' as hex
    from dual
    union all
    select '123255' as hex
    from dual
)

select *
from some_data
order by hex desc
;

Result:
123255
123A55
```

In MySQL DB it gives 123A55 in both cases.

Are there a different rules in ORACLE for sorting order for MAX() MIN() and ORDER BY?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/IQEy7_PT). Perhaps your server is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result depends on your environmental settings. Example:

```
with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select * from some_data order by hex desc;

HEX   
------
123A55
123255
```

But:

```
alter session set NLS_SORT='GERMAN';

with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select * from some_data order by hex desc;

HEX   
------
123255
123A55
```

MAX is not affected by setting the above in this case - same session:

```
with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select max(hex) from some_data;

MAX(HE
------
123A55
```

But setting another value in the same session:

```
alter session set NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC';

with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select max(hex) from some_data;

MAX(HE
------
123255
```

The above settings can be specified even at statement level.

```
with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select * from some_data order by NLSSORT(hex, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY') desc;

HEX   
------
123A55
123255

with some_data as
( select '123A55' as hex from dual union all
  select '123255' as hex from dual)
select * from some_data order by NLSSORT(hex, 'NLS_SORT = GERMAN') desc;

HEX   
------
123255
123A55
```